# Plotting summary of categorical data with Pandas

Tags: pandas

Consider this survey data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'wild':['little', 'little', 'very'], 'raw':['medium', 'medium', 'very'],
                   'rotten':['little', 'very', 'medium']})
```

I would like to summarize it. One way would be a scatter plot with 'wild', 'raw', and 'rotten' on the x-axis and 'very', 'medium', 'little' on the y-axis, in that order.

I've struggled with this but I cannot come up with the right way to do it.

Comment: Whoever downvotes, please help me understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scatter plot on categorical features does not make sense. To summarize these datas you could use a bar chart.

To do so, you could use countplot from seaborn :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'wild':['little', 'little', 'very'], 'raw':['medium', 'medium', 'very'],
               'rotten':['little', 'very', 'medium']})

sns.countplot(x="variable", hue="value", data=pd.melt(df))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yeah I was wondering about that myself. Do you think scatter is inappropriate even if the categories are ordered?

Comment: Yes, scatter plot is appropriate for quantitative data. For example, if you have height and weight of people you could apply scatter plot. More over if you have their sex you could identify in your scatter plot which point is male or female and this is the way to use categorical data in scatter plot

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is process your categories into values such as following,
You wil have  'wild', 'raw', and 'rotten' on the x-axis and a score on the y-axis corresponding to the mean of the mapped values of ''little', 'medium' and 'very'

```
mapping = {'little': 1, 'medium': 2,'very':3}
df=df.replace({'raw': mapping, 'rotten': mapping,'wild':mapping})
x=['raw','rotten','wild']
plt.scatter(x,df.mean())
```